# R - Tidymodels - Error when using a glm model within a workflow_set

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am triyng to fit many `glm` models to my dataset, to select the best performing one, using the `tidymodels` package. Since I'd like to try different combinations of preprocessing and model specifications, I am using the `workflow_set()` function to generate them, and `workflow_map()` to fit them and get performance metrics.

However, when applying `workflow_map()` to the workflows, I get a cryptic error:

> Error in if (rlang::call_name(x) == "tune") {: argument is of length zero

The most I could discover is that this error is returned by the function `check_fn()` whitin the `workflow_map()` function, but I don't understand the underlying problem in my code.

How can I use a glm model within a `workflow_set`?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

data("mtcars")

glm_recipe = recipe(hp ~ disp, data = mtcars)

glm_model = linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("glm", family = stats::gaussian("log"))

glm_workflows = workflow_set(list(glm_recipe), list(glm_model))

# fitting and predicting works
glm_workflows %>% extract_workflow("recipe_linear_reg") %>% fit(mtcars) %>% predict(mtcars)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 1
#>    .pred
#>    <dbl>
#>  1  117.
#>  2  117.
#>  3  103.
#>  4  151.
#>  5  195.
#>  6  138.
#>  7  195.
#>  8  113.
#>  9  112.
#> 10  120.
#> # ... with 22 more rows

# this doesn't work
workflow_map(glm_workflows)
#> Error in if (rlang::call_name(x) == "tune") {: argument is of length zero
#> Execution stopped; returning current results
#> # A workflow set/tibble: 1 x 4
#>   wflow_id          info             option    result    
#>   <chr>             <list>           <list>    <list>    
#> 1 recipe_linear_reg <tibble [1 x 4]> <opts[0]> <list [0]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because what you passed to `family` was namespaced.
Switching `family = stats::gaussian("log")` with `family = gaussian("log")` will resolve this error. A bug report have been [filed here](https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/issues/745).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

data("mtcars")

glm_recipe = recipe(hp ~ disp, data = mtcars)

glm_model = linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("glm", family = gaussian("log"))

glm_workflows = workflow_set(list(glm_recipe), list(glm_model))

splits = vfold_cv(mtcars)

workflow_map(glm_workflows, resamples = splits)
#> # A workflow set/tibble: 1 × 4
#>   wflow_id          info             option    result   
#>   <chr>             <list>           <list>    <list>   
#> 1 recipe_linear_reg <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[1]> <rsmp[+]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>